# Plant appears to die quickly

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, watering, plant-care

Bought this plant a fortnight ago and it was in perfect health. Suddenly it’s whittling away. Any reason this could happen so quickly. It’s not too hot, too cold, nor is it heavily watered. It looks like it may be drying, but I can’t tell if this is simply a pant that needs heavy/daily watering.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Might be underwatering, did you give it any water? How does the soil feel if you put your fingers in it?

Comment: caterpiller celosia? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=caterpiller+celosia+plant&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variety of Acalypha hispida, common name Chenille Plant. They like to be kept well watered, but not left sitting in water; that means a pot that allows water to drain away freely, not leaving any outer pot or tray full of water, but emptying it 30 minutes after watering, then making sure to water again before it dries out to keep it moist. It's one of those plants that likes what sound like impossible conditions described as 'moist but well drained'.

It doesn't look as if the container its in has drainage holes - if you've planted straight into that, there's the probable cause of the trouble. If the plant is in a pot with drainage holes inside that container, then perhaps you've not been emptying it out after watering, or just not giving sufficient water. These plants also require at the minimum very bright daylight, but preferably full sun when grown indoors, and minimum temperatures of 60 deg F (even at night). More info here https://www.hortmag.com/plants/plants-we-love/chenille-plant-an-interesting-flowering-houseplant

Comment: If that's a ceramic or clay pot, you can use masonry bits to drill drainage holes. I use a drill press, but careful work with a drill should work. Just take it slow and easy. Of course, the plant will have to come out first.